# Script to copy files not ending

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, copy-item

I have a script that will copy files from a set of folder(s) which match a specific string to a location. The script runs fine for the first server, but on the second it just never ends. I have a write-host step so I know when the first server is done. There are files written from the second server but it never gets to the second write-host command. Any thoughts? [for context the folders I want to search contain "cust+$AppType* and the files are *$LogDate_$LogHour*.log   - these steps work as expected and logs are found and copied for CUST001 server]
Script is below:

```
$AppType = Read-Host "What App Server do you need calls from? (MCP,RM,SIP,URS,ORS,WFM,WEB,GIR) [can also use * for all servers]"
$LogDate = Read-Host "What date was the call? (yyyymmdd)"
$LogHour = Read-Host "What hour was the call? (hh) [can also use * for entire day]"
$UserName = Read-Host "What is your UserID? (files will be places on Host SAMPLE2\c:\users\*USERID*\Desktop)"
$SrchString = Read-Host "What string are you searching for? (can use connid or ANI for example)"
$LogName = "*"+$LogDate+"_"+$LogHour+"*.log"
$Folder = "*cust"+$AppType+"*"
Get-ChildItem \\customer001\e$\Logs\$Folder -Filter $LogName -Recurse | Select-String $SrchString | Copy-Item -Destination \\SAMPLE2\c$\users\$UserName\Desktop -Force
Write-Host "Finished copying 001 files...."
Get-ChildItem \\customer002\e$\Logs\$Folder -Filter $LogName -Recurse | Select-String $SrchString | Copy-Item -Destination \\SAMPLE2\c$\users\$UserName\Desktop -Force
Write-Host "Finished copying 002 files...."
Exit
```

Comment: Is there any error output? Can you trying running the `Get-ChildItem` with the `-verbose` switch?

Comment: Right now you are coping the logs as many times as a matched line is found by select-string.  Change `Select-String $SrchString` to `Where-Object { $_ | Select-String $SrchString -Quiet }`